# add new coloumn to existing data base in android

Tags: android

I have a database when i try to add new column to that my app fore close

07-04 17:06:48.783: E/AndroidRuntime(17193): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: vpath: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body, reminder_date_time, vpath FROM reminders
 this the error please help me anyone.

Comment: Why are you using SELECT query to add vpath ? You should use ALTER query to add new column.

Answer (score 1):

Adding column :

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE reminders ADD vpath text");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_BODY + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null, "+ KEY_VOICE + " text not null,);";
```

I have remove "," at the end of the query then my problem is solved.

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_BODY + " text not null, " 
                    + KEY_DATE_TIME + " text not null, "+ KEY_VOICE + " text not null);";
```